# ResourceExhausted error while training nasnet_large on cifar10 on Kubernetes

Tags: tensorflow, kubernetes

I am trying to train nasnet on cifar10 on Kubernetes. I am getting this error:

> ResourceExhausted. 
>   "tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.ResourceExhaustedError: OOM when allocating tensor with shape[32,1008,42,42]
>   [[Node: cell_6/strided_slice = StridedSlice[Index=DT_INT32, T=DT_FLOAT, begin_mask=3, ellipsis_maseplica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"](cell_6/Pad, gradients/cell_stem_1/strided_slice_grad/StridedSliceGrad-1-Layoptimizer, gradients/cell_stem_1/strided_slice_grad/StridedSliceGrad-3-LayoutOptimizer)]]"

The repo [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/slim).

The command I used to train: `python train_image_classifier.py --train_dir=/tmp/train_logs --dataset_name=cifar10 --dataset_split_name=train --dataset_dir=tmp//data//cifar10 --model_name=nasnet_large`

CUDA Version 9.0.176
GPU (TensorFlow) 1.9.0
Ubuntu 16.04

Pod resource:
CPU:             28
Memory:          64Gi
GPU (NVIDIA):    2

Question 1: What should I do to resolve this error?
Question 2: Alternatively, how can I train on a single GPU only, in case if I want to?

Comment: Make sure to decrease the batch size from `32` to something smaller like `8`. Right now, your code fails because it can't allocate a Tensor with size `32 x 1008 x 42 x 42.

Comment: @gorjan Thank you. It worked.